Find value of $x$ s.t. a set of pairs of vectors are linearly dependent.
This is the first exercise, in the book: Linear algebra thorough Geometry, by Banchoff
For which choice of $x$ will the following pairs be linearly dependent, over the domain of $\mathbb {R}.$
(a) $(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  x \\
  1 \\
 \end{array} \right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  4 \\
  2 \\
 \end{array} \right)),$ (b) $(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  x \\
  x^2 \\
 \end{array} \right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  -3 \\
  9 \\
 \end{array} \right)),$ (c) $(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  x \\
  1 \\
 \end{array} \right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  9 \\
  x \\
 \end{array} \right)),$ (d) $(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  x \\
  x^2 \\
 \end{array} \right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  1 \\
  x \\
 \end{array} \right))$
Took clue from the first section there, which states the polar form of a vector $X,$ as a scalar multiple of a unit vector:
Any vector on the unit circle can be described by its angle $\theta$ (the polar angle of the vector) from the ray along the positive $x-$axis to the ray along the unit vector.
We may then write the unit vector using trigonometric functions as $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  \cos\theta \\
  \sin\theta \\
 \end{array} \right)$

If $X$ is any vector, then have:
$X= |X|(\frac 1{|X|}X) =  |X|\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  \cos\theta \\
  \sin\theta \\
 \end{array} \right) =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  |X|\cos\theta \\
  |X|\sin\theta \\
 \end{array} \right) $ for some angle $\theta.$
Hoped to take the polar form expression, for the two vectors (in each of the four pairs), and as linear dependence needs only a multiple; hence can take just the ratio of the polar angles, of the two vectors as equal.
But, am not sure. Hence, request to vet:
(a) is very easy to solve, by taking the equality of ratios of the corresponding components, which : $\frac x1 = \frac 42\implies x =2.$
(b) Taking clue from the approach used in (a), to get: $\frac x{x^2} = \frac {-3}9\implies 9x =-3x^2\implies 3x(x+3)=0.$
But, $x=0$ seems inapplicable here. So, $x=-3.$
Even taking any multiple of $x=-3$ is seemingly not possibly a solution. Also, for $x=-6, $ get $x^2=36.$ 
And, now $\frac x{x^2} =>\frac {-6}{36} \ne \frac {-3}9.$
Hence, seems only a single value, i.e. $x=-3$ should work.
(c) Taking the old approach, get: $\frac x1 = \frac 9x\implies x=\pm 3;$ but only $x=3$ works.
Am unclear if $x=-3$ will work too, i.e.  $\frac {-3}1 = \frac 9{-3}?$
(d) Get: $\frac x{x^2} = \frac 1x\implies$ it works for all possible values of $x$ in the domain of real numbers.

For c, $x=-3$ works too, i.e., $\frac{-3}1=\frac9{-3}$

For b, why do you say $x=0$ is inapplicable?  For d, $x=0$ is an answer, but you should not divide by $0$

@J.W.Tanner Unable to understand why $x=0$ works for the (b) case; seems you are considering only the equality $3x(x+3) = 0.$ But, am considering also the form $\frac x{x^2} = \frac{-3}9.$ It also implies $\frac 1x = \frac{-1}3,$ which makes the value $x=0$ not work.

For b, when $x=0$ then $\pmatrix{x\x^2}=\pmatrix{0\0}=0\pmatrix{-3\9}$

Note that in your "polar form" expression you divided by $\lvert X\rvert$, assuming it's not zero, so you should consider the zero case separately

It seems you didn't really make use of your "polar form" in solving the problems

For a, I agree with your answer.
For b, why do you say $x=0$ is inapplicable?!
For c, $x=-3$ works too; as you said, $\dfrac{-3}1=\dfrac9{-3}$.
For d, $x=0$ is an answer, but you should consider $0$ separately rather than dividing by it.

Tried also the method stated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411324/424260. Can there be a reason stated for the equivalence for these two, i.e. equating the polar form of the vectors, as in OP; & that of the link? The link talks about having a set of linear equations, based on two vectors, in each part: $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 = \mathbf 0.$ Say, in (a) above, get by the link's approach: $$
c_1\begin{bmatrix} x \ 1 \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix} 4 \ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \ 0\end{bmatrix} \implies c_1 x + 4 c_2 = 0, c_1 + 2c_2 =0 \implies c_1(x-2)=0 \implies x=2.$$

The classic definition of linearly dependent is you can find coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ not both $0$ so $c_1\vec{v_1}+c_2\vec{v_2}=0$.  If $\vec{v_1}=\vec{0}$ then it's easy:  just take any non-zero $c_1$ and $c_2=0$

I agree with your comment above; you have shown that what you have done to solve the  problem is equivalent to the classic definition, as long as you're not dividing by $0$; e.g., $c_1x+4c_2=0, c_1+2c_2=0\implies c_1x=-4c_2$ and $c_2=-2c_2$, and taking the ratio (assuming $c_2\ne0$) implies $x=\dfrac42$
